# Add QWERTY (language-agnostic) software keyboard on iOS

Tags: keyboard, ios

I have a problem with adding a language-agnostic QWERTY (software) keyboard on an iPhone 4S. On my iPhone 5S and my iPad Air I have added this QWERTY keyboard which is like the regular English (US) keyboard, but which doesn't do spell checking, etc. I know I can turn off spell checking completely, but this isn't really a solution, since I use the phone to write in English, and I use the spell checker.

FYI, here is how my Keyboards screen looks on the iPhone 5S:

[image]

On the iPhone 4S, I cannot add the "QWERTY" keyboard.

**EDIT**: None of the devices mentioned are jailbroken.

**EDIT 2**: My locale is set to Slovenian (Slovenia), in case it makes any difference.

Comment: You presumably are talking about an iphone you have jailbroken in some way, right?  Is there perhaps a forum connected with whatever method you used to do that?

Comment: No, the QWERTY keyboard pictured above is built-in. None of my devices are jailbroken.

Comment: Interesting!  I have no such keyboard available on my iPad Mini 7.0.4 and have never heard of it before.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't show up on mine as well, that's the problem :)

Comment: Apple doesn't normally vary software this way, but it may be that only certain devices have that keyboard as an option.

Comment: Other than reset or restore there isn't much you can do to fix something that doesn't work on an ios device.  Have you tried those.

Comment: I have tried restarting it, but not restoring it.